# Laravel validator compare one value to another only if both are present

Tags: php, laravel, validation, comparison

I'm using Laravel version v8.29.0

I am using the Laravel validator to validate values passed in from an HTTP request. In the request, I have an array of objects, each object has a `min` and a `max` value.

Right now I have this validation in place to make sure that the `min` value is less than the `max` value as well as that the `max` value is greater than the `min` value:

```
$this->validate($request, [    
    'someObject.*.someOtherObject.yetAnotherObject.min' => 'nullable|numeric|lte:someObject.*.someOtherObject.yetAnotherObject.max',
    'someObject.*.someOtherObject.yetAnotherObject.max' => 'nullable|numeric|gte:someObject.*.someOtherObject.yetAnotherObject.min',
]);
```

This works just fine if both values are passed in, but for my application it is allowed for just one or the other or neither to be passed in.

If I only pass in the `max` value then I get an error message that says the `max` value needs to be greater than the `min` value even though the `min` value was not passed in.

Same thing for the `min` value, if I only pass in the `min` value then I get an error message that says the `min` value must be less than the `max` value.

My question is what syntax changes do I need to make to the code above to allow one or the other, neither or both values for `min` and `max` to be passed in and only validate the `min` and `max` in regards to each other if they are both passed in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in way to conditionally use the `lte` and `gte` depending on if the other value is present.

What you could do is use the array syntax and a [Closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures) instead:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'someObject.*.someOtherObject.yetAnotherObject.min' => [
        'nullable',
        'numeric',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
            $max = $request->input(str_replace('min', 'max', $attribute));
            if (isset($value, $max) && $value > $max) {
                $fail(__('validation.lte.numeric', ['value' => $max]));
            }
        },
    ],
    'someObject.*.someOtherObject.yetAnotherObject.max' => [
        'nullable',
        'numeric',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
            $min = $request->input(str_replace('max', 'min', $attribute));
            if (isset($value, $min) && $value < $min) {
                $fail(__('validation.gte.numeric', ['value' => $min]));
            }
        },
    ],
]);
```

In the above, I'm also using [__()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-__) (translate) helper function to get the default error message that Laravel would have returned.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, tried it but I still get the error that says `min` must be less than the `max` if I only send in the `min` value and not the `max` value

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak Ah, of course. Sorry about that! Definitely had a "Duh" moment. I think the only option would be to use a [Custom Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) or a [Closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures) at this point.

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak I've updated my answer with something that should work for you. I've just tested it with a missing `min`, a missing `max`, a `min > max` and something that should pass and it all seem to give the correct results.

Comment: the only thing that I had to change with your answer was where you use `Str::replace`. I swapped in `str_replace(` instead and it works like a charm. Marked as accepted answer and upvoted. Thank you so much!